# Egit installation failed for IBM RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit, ibm-rad

I am trying to install git plugin for IBM RAD 8.0.4 . I came to know that 8.0.4 RAD is built on top of eclipse 3.6.2. So I have downloaded egit 2.1 zip from following link

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F

I tried to install this plugin by following steps:
Help-->Install new software-->click on add-->archive-->choose the egit zip file.

But I am getting the following issue

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

> Software being installed: EGit Plug-in Import Support
>   2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r)   Missing requirement: EGit Plug-in Import Support 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.import.feature.group
>   2.1.0.201209190230-r) requires 'org.eclipse.team.core 3.6.100' but it could not be found

I tried 2.0 as well, I have got following issue

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: EGit Mylyn
>   2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r)   Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not
>   be found

Can anybody suggest me which version of egit is supported for IBM RAD 8.0.4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to Uncheck EGit Import Support feature, EGit Mylyn. Got the answer from below link

http://www.programering.com/a/MDOzYTNwATY.html

Thank you rest_day

Answer (score 0):

EGit Import Support featue is not supported in Eclipse 3.6. It requires Eclipse 3.8 or higher.

Unselect the EGit Import Support feature when installing and the error should go away.

Comment: wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.0#Support_for_Eclipse-SourceReferences_manifest_headers

Comment: I have unchecked EGit Import Support feature..But still got the same issue.

Comment: Is it the exact same error messsage? Which features *are* you selecting? You should only need the Git UI feature.